# Simplifying Using the Laws of Equivalence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I am struggling with Simplifying Using the Laws of Equivalence and I'm unsure how to tackel larger 
equations (i.e. what order to simplify)

**for example**

show that $((A → B) ∨ (¬A → C)) → (B ∨ C) ≡ B ∨ C$

I think i must be applying the laws in the wrong order as I get them all to cancel out (like $P$ or not $P$ therefore true)

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a list of [Logical equivalences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence), which might be helpful.

\begin{align}
&((A \to B) \lor (\neg A \to C)) \to (B \lor C) \\
\equiv& \neg(A\to B)\land\neg(\neg A\to C)\lor(B\lor C)\tag*{Conditional equivalence}\\
\equiv&\neg(\neg A\lor B)\land\neg( A\lor C)\lor(B\lor C)\tag*{Conditional equivalence}\\
\equiv&A\land\neg B\land\neg A\land\neg C\lor(B\lor C)\tag*{De Morgan's law}\\
\equiv&A\land\neg A\land\neg B\land\neg C\lor(B\lor C)\tag*{Commutative law}\\
\equiv&\bot\land\neg B\land\neg C\lor(B\lor C)\tag*{Negation law}\\
\equiv&\bot\lor(B\lor C)\tag*{Domination law}\\
\equiv&B\lor C\tag*{Identity law}\\
\end{align}